# locate several column with specific values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, locate

Hel lo, I know how to use

```
`df2.loc[df2[2]=="gene"]` for instance
```

but let say I get from that:

```
                0         1     2        3        4     5  6  7   8
0  NW_011626968.1  AUGUSTUS  gene  1671821  1675615  0.04  -  .  g1
7  NW_011626968.1  AUGUSTUS  gene  1677196  1679599  0.13  +  .  g2
```

How can I also add the information of the col2 and 3 to match a specific values and get only the line 7  ?

I tried :

```
df2.loc[df2[2]=="gene"]  & df2.loc[df2[3]=="1677196"] & df2.loc[df2[4]=="1679599"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is necesary chain masks, not filtered rows, also are added `()` because priority of operators:

```
#if columns are filled by strings
#df3 = df2[(df2[2]=="gene") & (df2[3]=="1677196") & (df2[4]=="1679599")]

#if columns are filled by numbers
df3 = df2[(df2[2]=="gene") & (df2[3]==1677196) & (df2[4]==1679599)]
print (df3)
                0         1     2        3        4     5  6  7   8
7  NW_011626968.1  AUGUSTUS  gene  1677196  1679599  0.13  +  .  g2
```

Comment: It is said SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: oops, `]` was there

Comment: I get an empty result

Comment: there was typo `(df2[3]=="1679599")`, changed to `(df2[4]=="1679599")`

Comment: @Grendel - hmmm, maybe there are not strings, but numbers, answer was edited.

Comment: How well wth my true dataframe I get boolean result ex: ```[0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False```

Comment: @Grendel - hmmmm, it seems output of `(df2[2]=="gene") & (df2[3]==1677196) & (df2[4]==1679599)`, then need `df2[]` like `df2[(df2[2]=="gene") & (df2[3]==1677196) & (df2[4]==1679599)]`